# BootStrap Javascript Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Ok, so I attempted to implement a modal to my website but to my dismay, I've run into a problem where the firstly the modal is faded out and secondly, the text doesn't display nor am I able to click away.
[The modal on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKoXQ.png)

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">HORRAY!</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
```

Close
    
    
    
edit: I'm very new to Javascript, I only start coding again after a 5 year hiatus
edit: after trying fiddle, i've come to a guess that it's an issue in my css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is like this one, I believe the problem is in the space between data-dismiss. Despite that your code works just fine

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1637/

Comment: I would appreciate if you would actually take a look at the screenshot provided, hell I'll even provide a live demo of the error on my website.